# How can I let my website users change the font color without giving them access to the code?

Tags: html, colors, local-storage

If possible, can their preference be stored in localStorage?

Thank you in advance!

I am new to HTML.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for you to give website users ability to change anything on the webpage. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was able to save background images in localStorage, but only because of a question on here. My website is techtips.codehs.me if you want to see my code. I am new to HTML5 by the way.